# iOS Native Module - Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, upgrade, react-native-ios

I have an issue with upgrading react-native version from 0.59.10 to 0.61.5. We are using our own native modules and it seems like to be problem with them. This problem I have only on iOS.

#### ERROR:

**Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null.**

#### React Native version:

```
System:
   OS: macOS 10.15.2
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8259U CPU @ 2.30GHz
    Memory: 70.44 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 11.5.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.12.3 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.12.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 13.2, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.2, watchOS 6.1
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 27, 28, 29
      Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.0, 29.0.1, 29.0.2
      System Images: android-26 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
      Android NDK: 20.0.5594570
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.5791312
    Xcode: 11.3/11C29 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0
    react-native: 0.61.5 => 0.61.5
  npmGlobalPackages:
    react-native-cli: 2.0.1
    react-native-git-upgrade: 0.2.7
    react-native: 0.61.5
```

GITHUB: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27975

Comment: check this tutorial https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios. Unfortunately you do not have any example code or screenshot of what is your module structure or code in the module.